# EC2 Load Balancer - Security Access

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

On a AWS EC2 ELB security profile - i need a couple of IP Address to be able to access only certain pages of my website. Is it possible? The other IP Address will have access to the full website. Is this achievable

Answer (score 0):

This is **not possible** as a configuration in the Load Balancer because the Load Balancer simply distributes requests to your application servers.

Your **application** will need to enforce such functionality.